# msbuild/csproj exec task problem

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am having a problem on my build server(2003) with msbuild. I have narrowed down the issue to the exec task in the csproj file,which I have extracted into a very simple csproj(below), and still no joy, see the 'C:\Documents' error. This all works with no problems on my local machine.

I think there is some issue with an environment variable, but I cant figure it. Any advice?

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <Exec Command="echo hello world" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

MSBuild output

```
 D:\cc.net working\source\WebBase>msbuild ExecIssue.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/10/2010 12:37:50.
Project "D:\cc.net working\source\WebBase\ExecIssue.csproj" on node 1 (default t
argets).
BeforeBuild:
  echo hello world



'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.



D:\cc.net working\source\WebBase\ExecIssue.csproj(5,4): error MSB3073: The comma
nd "echo hello world" exited with code 1.
Done Building Project "D:\cc.net working\source\WebBase\ExecIssue.csproj" (defau
lt targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\cc.net working\source\WebBase\ExecIssue.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(BeforeBuild target) ->
  D:\cc.net working\source\WebBase\ExecIssue.csproj(5,4): error MSB3073: The com
mand "echo hello world" exited with code 1.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.17
```

Comment: IIRC, the executable and parameters are separate.

Comment: Exec invokes cmd.exe, and it seems to fail somehow; can you cmd normally? btw your example runs fine here

Comment: @stijn yea, no problem from cmd.exe at all.

Comment: Your example runs fine here too. It's weird that your msbuild is trying to access "C:\Documents", did you edit Microsoft.Common.Targets or some other global files? It seems to me that msbuild is writing "c:\Documents" in command line... Writing "C:\Documents" in command line produce the same error.

Comment: @bb no, didnt touch it/any of them at all. I'm having a look at that file,and the Microsoft.CSharp.targets right now, for any possible reference, but no joy. I think you're spot on with the not escaping the path, where and why are the next questions.

Comment: Have you run cmd.exe on the build server AS the user the build runs as?  Chances are something about that user's profile is causing cmd.exe to have some trouble getting to the path it needs to invoke

Comment: @taylor yea, done this, no joy either. at this stage, i'm willing to just write it off errant config bug somewhere, and reinstall the framework and or server.

Comment: You could do a exec command pwd and %USERNAME%, see if the output can shed some light over whats going on.  That error is coming from cmd, just not sure why

Comment: @taylor the exec command fails before any command is executed, so I cant get it to echo out %USERNAME% or even cd. As I mentioned below, I'm going to put it down to some screwy issue, and do reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I would run it in diagnostic mode and send it to a file and then search for C:\Documents in the file.  Maybe it's using "C:\Documents and settings\" in some path parameter without quoting it.  The diagnostic mode will print out most if not all of the properties, item groups, environment variables, etc that are in use.  Hopefully it will print out all the properties being used by the exec task, since you are only supplying the command parameter it is using some defaults for the rest of them.

```
msbuild ExecIssue.csproj /v:Diagnostic > buildout.txt
```

Comment: this was useful to see the paths, thanks for tip, but sadly no joy. cant see any obvious difference between the broken build, and the one on the local machine.

@alli'm going to put it down as a server issue, and reinstall the machine at this stage, as nothing obvious seems to be poping out from this. thanks for all the help guys